# 2 functions in a store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code, in the field value, is there a way that I can have 1 more function there beside removeEmptyString function?

```
var input1store = new Ext.data.Store({
fields: [{name: 'name', convert:removeEmptyString}],
proxy:{
type: 'ajax',
url:    'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source1',
        reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root:   'xml.result'
}
},
autoLoad:false,
sorters:    [{property: 'name', direction: 'asc'}]
});
```

To make it clear, I want 1 more function in the following code:

```
 fields: [{name: 'name', convert:removeEmptyString}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just create a function that will do both?

```
{
    name: 'name',
    convert: function(v){
        return myOtherFn(removeEmptyString(v));
    }
}
```